# Drupal Webform CiviCRM Warning message

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

When my Drupal CiviCRM Webform is filled out and submitted, the CiviCRM database appears to be updated correctly. That is, a new contact is created with all the proper information included from the form. The Webform confirmation page announces: "Thank you, your submission has been received." However, a red error box also appears that says:

"Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::postProcess() (line 1551 of /home/mywebsite/www/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php)."

Any idea what this means and how to get rid of the error message?

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.14.1

Answer (score 3):

That's just a notice -> best to hide all notices and errors on a production site:

go to your:
admin/config/development/logging

and set the radio button to:
None

Comment: Thanks much. That solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent - glad that helped you out. Next time I’m in the section I’ll have a look and check why we have that notice (and fix it) but the answer still is you never want to show notices and errors to your website visitors.