# I get a bunch of identical messages "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in element_children() ..."

Tags: civimember

My system upgraded from MySQL 5.7.30 to 8.0.

After that, CiviCRM was broken and I had to downgrade. I did it to Mysql 5.7.31 and the database ran again, but with a bunch of identical error messages at the top of my pages:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in element_children() (line 6656 of /usr/share/drupal/includes/common.inc).

I still have to perform some upgrades from CiviCRM 5.26.0 to 5.30.0

My additional question is: is it sufficient to upgrade CiviCRM to make the errors disappear or do I have to fix first the errors. In case I have to upgrade, I would like to know if it is better to upgrade in one shot from 5.26.0 to 2.30.0 or will I do it step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few items here:

- It's safe to upgrade CiviCRM from 5.26 to 5.30 in a single step.   As always, back up your database first, and if you need to restore it, it's safest to drop the existing contents before reimporting the backup.
- Notices should not be configured to appear on a production site, they're mainly of concern to developers.  Since you use Drupal you can [turn notices off from the UI](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31192/12).  Other should [change their php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867082).

Regardless, notices shouldn't prevent an upgrade, and moreover, the notices appear to be coming from Drupal, not CiviCRM.

Finally - I noticed that MySQL 5.7.31 doesn't like to export data unless you a) grant all privileges, or b) pass `--no-tablespaces` to `mysqldump`.  Either approach is fine.